# typeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list in if statement list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a list named `records` in which each element is composed of a list of 2 elements. I want to eliminate the element of the list of lists that has the value `b` in the second index of its list.

For this I am trying to use list comprehension:

`records = [i for i in records if records[i][1] != b]`

But I get a TypeError: `list indices must be integers or slices`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

Hi! In the code you provided, there is a misunderstanding of what a list comprehension is doing. When you write something like

```
[i for i in list ...
```

OR

```
for i in list:
   ...
```

"i" represents **the value itself**, not its index.

For example, if I were to write

```
for i in ["foo", "bar"]:
    print(i)
```

I would get the output

```
"foo"
"bar"
```

Knowing that, we can modify your code i order for it to work correctly

```
records = [i for i in records if i[1] != b]
```

### What this code does:

It iterates through each element inside records array and checks to see if index 1 of the array is different than b. If so, it appends the element to the new resulting list, which is then reassigned to the `records` variable.

If you have any questions, feel free to hit me up!

## Tips regarding your question:

You should try to be more descriptive in your questions by adding language (Python), version, and maybe some minimal example of a `record` for the question to be understood correctly.

## Tips regarding list comprehensions:

I would avoid focusing on them if you are newer to programming in general as (in my opinion) you should focus on fundamentals first and the level of abstraction in list comprehensions is quite high as it does many things under the hood. Cheers! Let me know if this solves your problem :)